# What's the purpose of (IN.uv.xyxy).xy)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I'v got a surface shader some other people wrote.And it works fine.However I see codes like this:

```
struct Input
{
    float2 uv;
    //...
}

void surf(Input IN,//...)
{
    float4 tex = tex2D(_Tex, (IN.uv.xyxy).xy);
}
```

...

I tried to replace `(IN.uv.xyxy).xy` with `IN.uv`. The output effect seems nothing different.

So I was wondering what does the `(.xyxy).xy` do?

Does the code have to be like this?Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In GLSL, this is known as [swizzle operation](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)).

You can use it to filter, reorder, and repeat float components.

You can use any combination of up to 4 of the letters to create a vector4 (of the same basic type) of that length.

So 
`IN.uv.xyxy`is a `vector4`, created using only x and y components on `uv` in repetition.

Then

`(IN.uv.xyxy).xy` is vector2 same type as `IN.uv` but so with called enhancement. I guess in your code these two would not be much different as its just like creating a Vector4 from Vector2 and then using its first 2 values to create Vector2.

Like in following example:

```
Vector2 v2 = new Vector2(2f,4f);
Vector4 v4 = new Vector4(v2.x, v2.y, v2.x, v2.y);
Vector2 v2_new = new Vector2(v4.x, v4.y); // same as v2
```

Any combination of up to 4 letters is acceptable, so long as the source vector actually has those components.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Umair, so I guess I can simply use IN.uv here, right? Thanks for your patiently explanation :D

Comment: Yes, but only in this special case where only xy is used. As uv has only xy and the vec4 constructed out of it is based on only xy of uv (vec2) if it makes sense. However if something like `(IN.uv.xyxy).yz` or `(IN.uv.xyxy).wx` comes up this would not be same as uv.